# z-indexing floating divs

Tags: css, z-index, css-float

I have two divs float:left. I z-index the first div to be above, but it doesn't work. Is this because floated elements are not positioned?

```
<html>

<style>
    #wrap{
        background:#666;
    }

    #menu, #thumbs{
        float:left;
    }

    #menu{
        background:#06C;
        z-index:10;
    }
    #thumbs{
        background:#0CF;
        margin-left:-20px;
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrap">
    <div id="menu">
    <p>menu</p>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
    <p>thumbs</p>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to set the `position` property. Adding `position:relative` to `#menu` displays the menu div above thumbs.

Comment: You guys are too good! Thanks stackers! This solved the problem.