# Bootstrap modal is not showing, on button click, when button have inline style with float rule - on mobile devices

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

The following code doesn't show the modal on button click, on mobile devices, when the button have an inline style float rule:

```
<button class="aa-secondary-btn" style="float: left; width: 140px;" title="Add a new product." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Add New</button>
                    
<!--add product modal-->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="modal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--/add product modal-->
```

It's only when I remove the float rule that the modal shows. What should I do to have the button float and have the modal show on mobile devices?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018572/z-indexing-floating-divs

Comment: No, but I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: @A.Meshu, how does this relate to the button click to show a modal? The reason I didn't try it is that I don't understand the relationship of it to my problem. Will you explain?

Comment: Since you didn't provide your whole markup it seems that SOMETHING overlaps the button when you float it (might happen while floating elements) - so if you want to set button's position out of the page's flow - use `absolute` position and `z-index` instead. Update your question and i can show you exactly how.

Comment: I think something is overlapping the button because I can't even select it when I try to inspect it.  I did solve my problem with margin-left: calc(100%-140px); instead of floating it. That works for me now. Thank you for your willingness though. I appreciate it. ;-)

Comment: I think you mean relative position. You're a genius. You're solution works.

Comment: Glad you solve it.

Answer (score 0):

By using Meshu's suggestion I solved my problem and now the modal shows. Actually, the button is clickable. Below is the solution code:

```
<button class="aa-secondary-btn" style="position: relative; z-index: 20;width: 140px; float: right;" title="Add a new product." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_prod_mod">Add New</button>
                            
<!--add product modal-->
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="add_prod_mod" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```